# 'float:none' property between every 3 'li' using CSS

Tags: css, css-float, less

Here I have created a `ul li` list with `float:left` for each `li` tag. And added `float:none;` inline property for every third `li`. I want to make it with condition using CSS only.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    ul
    {
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li
    {
        margin-right:10px;
        float:left;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li style="float:none;">List 3</li>

    <li>List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li style="float:none;">List 6</li>

    <li>List 7</li>
    <li>List 8</li>
    <li style="float:none;">List 9</li>

    <li>List 10</li>
    <li>List 11</li>
    <li style="float:none;">List 12</li>

    <li>List 13</li>
    <li>List 14</li>
    </ul>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: so what is the question? Please be more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `ul li:nth-child(3n)` to target every third `li` element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SL6G/)

```
ul li {
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
ul li:nth-child(3n) {
    float:none;
}
```

If you wanted to get fancy, you could use `:not()` to exclude the third `li` elements from the initial styling and avoid having to overwrite `float:left`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tScf8/)

```
ul li:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-child(3n){
    float:none;
}
```

add this to css instead of inline style. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
ul  {
    list-style:none
}
ul li
{
float:left;
position:absolute;
}
```

here if set the child class like li mean its take separate .